# Spring Cloud Contract base64 image upload to long

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

How can we create a contract for an image upload in base 64? 
These base64 strings tend to get very long and we seem to get this exception:

```
String too long. The given string is 500000 Unicode code units long, but only a maximum of 65535 is allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to upload such a gigantic image for a contract test? You want to use contract testing to just check whether your application can parse an image, not parse gigantic images. For the latter tests you can do integration testing. In my opinion you're misusing the tool.

Comment: The image is not as gigantic as you would think. I have been testing a bit and 500x500 pixels is 73515 so you are quite fast at the limit.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. So there are 2 problems here. One is that in sc-contract we're converting any file to string which causes the problem. The other one is that you can assert the contract test with an image of 1x1 pixel. Cause what you want to assert is whether you can parse binary content, right?